# If statement answer keeps looping

Tags: python

The aim of this code is to get the computer to generate a random number and let the user try and guess what that number is in however many tries they choose. However, when they fail to guess correctly the program is supposed to print "You have failed in (x) tries" just once. Unfortunately this line keeps looping over and over again. Where have I gone wrong?

```
import random

def guess(x):

    random_number = random.randint(1,x)
    guess = 0
    tries = 0
    limit = int(input("How many tries would you like to have? "))

    while guess != random_number:
        if tries < limit:
            guess = int(input(f"Guess a random number between 1 and {x} in {limit} tries: " ))
            if guess < random_number:
                print("too low")
            elif guess > random_number:
                print("too high")
        else:
            print(f"You have failed in {limit} tries")
        tries = tries + 1

    print (f"You have guessed {random_number} correctly")

guess(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to keep a check of the `tries`.
- You need to print the statement only in the user input is correct:

```
import random

def guess(x):

    random_number = random.randint(1,x)
    guess = 0
    tries = 0
    limit = int(input("How many tries would you like to have? "))

    while tries<limit:
        if tries < limit:
            guess = int(input(f"Guess a random number between 1 and {x} in {limit} tries: " ))
            if guess < random_number:
                print("too low")
            elif guess > random_number:
                print("too high")
            else:
                print (f"You have guessed {random_number} correctly")
                break
        else:
            print(f"You have failed in {limit} tries")
        tries = tries + 1

    
guess(10)
```

---

You can use a `for` loop:

```
import random

def guess(x):

    random_number = random.randint(1,x)
    guess = 0
    tries = 0
    limit = int(input("How many tries would you like to have? "))
    found=False
    for i in range(limit):
        guess = int(input(f"Guess a random number between 1 and {x} in {limit} tries: " ))
        if guess < random_number:
            print("too low")
        elif guess > random_number:
            print("too high")
        else:
            
            found=True
            break
    if found:
        print (f"You have guessed {random_number} correctly")
    else:
        print(f"You have failed in {limit} tries")
        

    
guess(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

It was looping forever because the **incrementation of** `tries` was done in the **else block** and there is **no `break` keyword** in else block too.

So, **move** `tries = tries+1` in the `if tries <limit:` **block** and **put** `break` **inside the else block** as shown below:

```
import random

def guess(x):

    random_number = random.randint(1,x)
    guess = 0
    tries = 0
    limit = int(input("How many tries would you like to have? "))

    while guess != random_number:
        if tries < limit:
            guess = int(input(f"Guess a random number between 1 and {x} in {limit} tries: " ))
            if guess < random_number:
                print("too low")
            elif guess > random_number:
                print("too high")
                
            tries = tries + 1 # <--- move here
        else:
            print(f"You have failed in {limit} tries")
            break;  # <--- put break

    print (f"You have guessed {random_number} correctly")

guess(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple logical errors in your code,

- the condition you are using in the while loop, `guess != random_number`, is to check if a number has been guessed correctly or not, not to check if the total number of guesses are exhausted.
- No matter what happens, when the code will exit the while loop it will show the user that he/she has guessed correctly

Changing your code to take this into consideration will fix your problem. Below is a possible solution:

```
import random

def guess(x):
    random_number = random.randint(1,x)
    guess = 0
    tries = 0
    limit = int(input("How many tries would you like to have? "))

    # Flag to check if the user is guessing the right or wrong value
    # Default assumption is that user is guessing incorrectly
    UserGuess = False
    
    while tries < limit:

        guess = int(input(f"Guess a random number between 1 and {x} in {limit} tries: " ))
        if guess < random_number:
            print("too low")
        elif guess > random_number:
            print("too high")
        else:
            # Changing flag and stopping the loop if the user guesses correctly
            UserGuess = True
            break
        
        tries = tries + 1

    if UserGuess:
        print (f"You have guessed {random_number} correctly")
    else:
        print (f"You have failed in {limit} tries")

guess(10)
```